# How test if date is null in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, where-clause

I need to test if a date is not null in where condition:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM employe WHERE date IS NOT NULL date > ? AND date IS NOT NULL date < ? ";
PreparedStatement statement = connessione_db.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setDate(1, data_interval_1);
statement.setDate(1, data_interval_2);
```

The `date` must be between `data_interval_1` and `data_interval_2` and `data_interval_1` and `data_interval_2` can be null.

Comment: Just an FYI, you're much better off to use stored procedures instead of hardcoding SQL statements in your java code. Reference: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:296373600346847268

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do the check for `NULL`, because if the date is `NULL`, the range check will automatically fail.  Try this version:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM employe WHERE date > ? AND date < ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connessione_db.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setDate(1, data_interval_1);
statement.setDate(2, data_interval_2);
```

Note: In your code above you were binding both interval dates to the same position.  You want to bind to both positions 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Just to test if `date` is not null, you would do:

```
where date is not null
```

However, for the conditions, you can do:

```
where date >= ? and date <= ?
```

A `null` value can never meet the conditions, so this implicitly does a `null` check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM employe WHERE date IS NOT NULL AND (date > ? AND date < ?)
```

We first check if the date is null. 
If this condition its true, then it will check if the date is inside the range.